# More elegant way of defining array contents

Tags: c#, arrays, xna

I am trying to define the contents of an array. A way of achieving what I want is shown below for a simplified example.

Is there a better way of doing it? This seems like a pretty messy way of achieving something that I feel should be easily done. Could I use lists? Or would a database work (I don't know anything about how to use databases but feel that this is the kind of thing they would be good at).

Thanks in advance

```
        for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfBoxes; i++)
        {

            BoxName[0] = "Blue box";
            if (i == 1) { break; }
            BoxName[1] = "Red box";
            if (i == 2) { break; }
            BoxName[2] = "Yellow box";
            if (i == 3) { break; }
            BoxName[3] = "Green box";
            if (i == 4) { break; }
            BoxName[4] = "White box";
            if (i == 5) { break; }
            BoxName[5] = "Black box";
            if (i == 6) { break; }
        }
```

What I really want to do is to just use this code:

```
            BoxName[0] = "Blue box";
            BoxName[1] = "Red box";
            BoxName[2] = "Yellow box";
            BoxName[3] = "Green box";
            BoxName[4] = "White box";
            BoxName[5] = "Black box";
```

And if there are only 4 boxes then the compiler just magically knows to ignore BoxName[4] and BoxName[5] rather than throwing an error like it currently does.

Comment: Can you clarify where the data comes from? Are you able to just hard code it, or do you actually *need* something like a database? (You could load them items from a file into an array or a list, for example.) More context will help us provide better answers.

Comment: For now hard coding is fine for testing purposes, but I'm rapidly reaching the point where I need to build a database. In the end I've just used a try/catch (see my answer below)

Comment: Can you give more details? It's really not clear what the context is... What relations do you have between your data? Will it need to change after installation? (There are lots of ways of supplying data to an app... Don't assume you'll need to jump straight to a database.)

Comment: The program (a text based game) will take the data (start conditions of the game) and read and update it as the game progresses (and also somehow save and re load it). I'm open to any advice/ideas you have on the best way to do this (with a database or otherwise), I'm just hesitant to ask a question along the lines of "What's the best way to manage data in a database based text based game?" as I know how those tend to go down here!

Comment: You should probably start by thinking about which data is static (won't change over the course of the game) and which data is dynamic (player positions, health etc). Then consider whether or not it's feasible to hold everything in memory - if it is, then you may well find it's simpler just to use plain files rather than a database. Databases are great for efficient querying, but I suspect that's not a requirement here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using *Linq*:

```
// All possible boxes
String[] possibleBoxes = new String[] {
  "Blue box",
  "Red box",
  "Yellow box",
  "Green box",
  "White box",
  "Black box"
};

int numberOfBoxes = 4; // Or 6 or 3...

String[] BoxName = possibleBoxes.Take(numberOfBoxes).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create one array with all the options, and then just copy as many as you need:

```
// This declaration could be for a private static readonly variable, given that
// you won't change the contents
string[] allBoxes = { "Blue box", "Red box", "Yellow box", "Green box",
                      "White box", "Black box" };
Array.Copy(allBoxes, BoxName, NumberOfBoxes);
```

If you don't already have the array, you could potentially use a `List<string>`, fill it completely, then use `List<T>.RemoveRange` to trim it:

```
List<string> boxes = new List<string> { "Blue box", "Red box", "Yellow box",
                                        "Green box", "White box", "Black box" };
boxes.RemoveRange(numberOfBoxes, boxes.Count - numberOfBoxes);
```

Or use LINQ:

```
List<string> boxes = new[] { "Blue box", "Red box", "Yellow box",
                             "Green box", "White box", "Black box" }
                     .Take(numberOfBoxes)
                     .ToList(); // Or ToArray if you really want an array
```

There are really lots of options.

It's not really clear what your situation is though - there may be better alternatives. With more context, we can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is define the list of all possible values with their associated index in a dictionary, and build your array by picking up items in the dictionary.

```
var dic = new Dictionary<int, string> 
{
    { 0, "Blue box" },
    { 1, "Red box" }, 
    { 2, "Yellow box" }, 
    { 3, "Green box" }, 
    { 4, "White box" }, 
    { 5, "Black box" } 
};

string[] boxName = new string[4];   // only 4 items
for (int i = 0; i < boxName.Length; i++)
{
    boxName[i] = dic[i];
}
```

Comment: Why use a dictionary here? An array (or list) for "all boxes" makes more sense, given that the key in your dictionary is always an integer, starting with 0 and always increasing by one...

Comment: @JonSkeet The OP talked about a DB, I don't know where the data comes from. Maybe the input (the list of colors) is not ordered and you have to store the index. I can randomize the order in the dictionary if you prefer...

Comment: You seem to be introducing generality for no particular reason. Even if the input data *is* a set of { index, value } pairs, it would be easy to order that *once* to obtain an array. Given that your code will *only* work in the case where the keys are contiguous integers starting from 0, an array or a list seems a much more natural approach than a dictionary.

Comment: @JonSkeet The code is one thing, the explanation that comes with it is another. I suggested to "pick items from a dictionary to build the array". Looks like a general approach to me, as it would cover cases where there are no continuous indexes nor indexes starting from 0...

Comment: As I said: you're introducing generality for no particular reason. Why make things more complicated than they need to be, until that generality is actually required? I'd rather use a simpler solution until I *need* to make it more complicated.

Comment: @JonSkeet Maybe because the question is vague enough? Why was the OP taking about a DB if a simple array would work in any case?

Comment: Because the OP doesn't know how to do this simply, and thought (incorrectly, IMO) that a database *might* simplify it. There's no indication that the OP *needs* a database.

Comment: @JonSkeet I can understand the OP doesn't know how to do this simply, but talking about a database doesn't make any sense to me for _just_ the simplified example the OP wrote. The title of the question could suggest he wants a general way of achieving this, too.

Comment: Well, I disagree. I see no indication that the OP needs anything more general than "populate a potentially-smaller array from a well-known larger sequence of values". In order to use the generality your answer *sort-of* provides, more help would be needed anyway, so I really don't see that this approach is helpful as it stands.

Comment: @JonSkeet Well it's your opinion. When I see a vague question, I try to provide an answer that would cover more that a simple and contrived example. If you don't like my question, fine, just keep your downvote I don't care, I won't delete it.

Comment: I see no evidence that the example is contrived. I agree the question could be clearer, but I'd always prefer to provide a simple answer and ask for more context than to *assume* more complexity is really required. Note that none of the other answers have assumed that complexity is required - and you haven't asked the OP for any more details.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I actually  understand your problem but hope this helps:

```
List<string> BoxName = new List<string>() {"Blue box", "Red box", ...};
```

When you want to loop through your list just use:

```
BoxName.Count();
```

So you won't have an Out Of Bounds Exception.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, if this solution is what you need:

```
var BoxName = new string[] {"Blue box", "Red box", "Yellow box", "Green box", "White box",  "Black box" };
```

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to fix this myself in the short term with a try/catch statement. Apologies for not asking the question more clearly as this would probably have been a very obvious solution if I'd explained myself better.